# PHP email contact form, dropdown box for subject not working

Tags: php

I have a contact form that mails the user input values to an email address. It works fine, it sends with all the information except for the subject, which I have presented as a drop down box with a few choices. I want the selected option set as the email subject.

```
<select name="subject">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>


<?php
  $email      = $_POST['email'];
  $message    = $_POST['message'];
  $name       = $_POST['name'];
  $subject    = $_POST['subject'];
  $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
  $to         = 'emailaddress.co.uk';
  $from       = $email;
  $header     = "From:" . $from;
  $msgsubject = "$subject message from $name";
  $commessage = "Name: $name

  Email: $email

  Phone Number: $phone

  Subject: $subject

  Message: $message";

  mail($to, $msgsubject, $commessage, $header);
?>
```

Comment: you have a typo on line 1: subject]

Comment: Removed it, still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, you haven't provided a [testcase](http://sscce.org). Almost anything could be wrong at this point. You should do more debugging.

Comment: Everything else works, the email sends and information is in there. It's just getting the value from the drop down box. I thought maybe it was because I was trying to put the value in the subject, so I tried putting it in with the message, still didn't work. Sorry I'm new to PHP...maybe I should try changing the drop down box to an input area instead?

Comment: could I see the form tag?

Comment: Okay, I tried it as a textbox and it works fine. I really wanted it as a drop down box...is there something wrong with my html?

Comment: where is your form tag?

Comment: could I see the rest of your code including the form element and all elements within the form.

Comment: your select should really be within form tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="subject]">
```

`subject]`? Really?

(Hint: no!)

Comment: Dammit....that was from where I was told to put a '[]' at the end of the name and it would work. I just tried it again, without the ']' and it still doesn't work....any ideas?

Comment: I don't know why you were told that; it's nonsense.